# use scanner in method with reloadable menu

Tags: java, methods, menu, java.util.scanner

I can´t get my reloadable method "menu" to work and it looks like it has something to do with scanner.

I´m sure it´s an easy solution but I just can´t find it

```
 public class menuControl
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
{
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1: System.out.println(1); menu();break;
        case 2: System.out.println(2); menu();break;
        case 3: System.out.println(3); menu();break;
        case 4: System.out.println(4); menu();break;
        case 0: System.out.println(0); menu();break;
        }
}
    public static int menu()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choice 1");
        System.out.println("Choice 2");
        System.out.println("Choice 3");
        System.out.println("Choice 4");
        System.out.print("Choose: ");
        int choice = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        in.close(); 
        if (choice > 0 && choice < 5)
        {
            return choice;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong choice!");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Cashmachine.menu(Cashmachine.java:47) //The line"int choice = in.nextInt();"
    at Cashmachine.main(Cashmachine.java:23) //The line "case 1: System.out.println(1); menu();break;"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Exception in thread “main” java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found - Using scanner input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828015/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found-usi).

Comment: do you really want bad input to default to zero? You could give users another chance

Comment: Yes, if the user makes a bad input it will jump back to menu choice so he will get another chance. As per the suggestion with the for statement. I had tried a different approach that didn´t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `in.close()`. Your `Scanner` in wraps the global `System.in`, once you `close()` it you will not be able to use `nextInt()`.

You could extract the `Scanner` to a field (or an argument) like

```
public static int menu(Scanner in) {
    // Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // ...
    // in.close();
    // ...
```

And I think you wanted a loop in `main()` like

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (;;) {
    switch (menu(in)) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println(1);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println(2);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println(3);
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println(4);
        break;
    case 0:
        System.out.println(0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to declare and initialize the scanner in a field, so that a new one doesn't need to be created each time you all the function.