# Scanner Issue with Java String Parsing

Tags: java

Feel like I'm missing something really basic here, but my brain is fried right now. Goal is to parse strings with a comma, gets through one loop and throws before the next line. Pretty sure it has something to do with userInput = scan.nextLine();

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseStrings
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userInput = "";
  boolean finished = false; 

  while (!finished) 
  {
     System.out.print("Enter input string: \n");

     userInput = scan.nextLine();

     if (userInput.equals("q"))
     {
        System.out.println("First word: " + userInput);
        finished = true; 
     } else
     {
        String[] userArray = userInput.split(",");
        System.out.println("First word: " + userArray[0]);
        System.out.println("Second word: " + userArray[1]);
        System.out.println();
     }
  }
  return;
 }
}
```

Throwing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at ParseStrings.main(ParseStrings.java:12)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce. How are you running your program?

Comment: Its through Zybooks

Comment: Is that an online IDE? Does it support input through scanner and system.in?

Comment: Are you getting this error consistently?  Is this all of the code? Seems like input is being closed.  You can also add while(!finished || !scan.hasNextLine()) to make sure that scanner is not closed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828015/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found-usi

Comment: Added scan.hasNextLine to the while statement and it throws the same error. Yes it supports input through scanner and system.in

Comment: @EdwardDurrett actually it should be  while(!finished && scan.hasNextLine())  what's your input?

Comment: @Yan Examples of input: Jane, Alice Blue,Dog. The problem definitely seems to be with the input closing. The while finishes when you have (!finished && scan.hasNextLine())

Comment: @EdwardDurrett I can't reproduce the issue.  Is this the full source code?  Here is online copy of your code and it runs as expected https://repl.it/repls/MerryFantasticSpadefoot  Just renamed the class to Main to be able to run it